# external USB hard drive will only format to 41 gigs although it used to format to 700 gigs/Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, format

I have an external hard drive, attached to a USB port, that used to format to about 700 gigs. I use  Acronis to make nightly backups of my C: drive, my system drive. Suddenly my log file showed that there wasn't enough room on the USB drive to make a copy –  I make a copy that replaces last night's copy. It has worked flawlessly for at least two or three years. When I went to reformat the drive it reformats but only to 41 GB!

I tried using Manage Disks and it, too, only allows for a reformat to 41 GB.

what is wrong and how do I fix it?

Thanks.

Ross

Comment: Have you tried a different computer ? Have you tried pulling the drive out and plugging it straight into a computer to see if it does the same thing ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using NTFS to format the drive? FAT32 has size limitations. I'm pretty sure the max is 32GB, which is strange because you said it's 41GB, but that's the first thing I'd check anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Make sure you are formatting the drive as NTFS
2. Make sure you are formatting the entire drive, and not just one of several partitions
3. Make sure that when you create a new partition you are selecting the whole drive and not just the first 41 gigs.

It's possible something is wrong with the drive.

1. Run CheckDisk (chkdsk) or fsck
2. Check the SMART data and make sure their are not problems.

Comment below with any results or additional questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are formatting one of the partitions and not the entire drive. This can be cleared by using a common partition software such as the free [Minitool Parition Wizard](http://download.cnet.com/MiniTool-Partition-Wizard-Home-Edition/3000-2094_4-10962200.html?part=dl-6285158&subj=dl&tag=button) Home Edition. Just select all the partitions. Delete them. make sure you backup all the essential data from the partitions.